# Laravel year, sum, count, group by eloquent query

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Can someone show me how I would build this query with eloquent, or is this required to be written with a DB:Raw query, or would it be best to be a raw sql query?

```
select `pay_week`,
       year(`start_timestamp`) as year,
       sum(`total_duration`) as 'duration',
       count(`pay_week`) as 'entries'
from `time_clock`
group by year(`start_timestamp`),`pay_week`;
```

Any help to better understand would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

```
$entries = TimeClock::select(
   'pay_week', 
   DB::raw('count(pay_week) as entries'), 
   DB::raw('YEAR(start_timestamp) as year'), 
   DB::raw('sum(total_duration) as duration')
)
->where('user_id', $user->record_id)
->sum('total_duration')
->groupBy('pay_week')
->get();
```

results in a

```
Call to a member function groupBy() on float
```

What I have now;

Blade;

```
<table class="table table-hover dataTable table-striped width-full" data-plugin="dataTable">
                                <thead>
                                    <th>Pay Week</th>
                                    <th>Date Range</th>
                                    <th>Year</th>
                                    <th>Total Hours</th>
                                    <th>Gross Pay</th>
                                    <th>Entries</th>
                                    <th>Action</th>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                @foreach($entries as $group)
                                    @foreach($group->entries as $entry)
                                        @php
                                            $week_start = (new DateTime())->setISODate(date("Y"),$entry->pay_week)->format("m/d");

                                            $start = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat("m/d", $week_start);
                                            $end = $start->copy()->endOfWeek()->format('m/d');
                                            $year = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($entry->start_timestamp)->format('Y');

                                        @endphp
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>{{ $entry->pay_week }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ $start->format('m/d') . ' - ' . $end }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ $year }}</td>
                                            <td>0</td>
                                            <td>$ 0.00</td>
                                            <td>0</td>
                                            <td>[ Btn ]</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    @endforeach
                                @endforeach
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
```

This is what I have in the controller method.

```
$user = Auth::guard('user')->user();

        $entries = TimeClock::select(
            'pay_week',
            'start_timestamp',
            'total_duration'
        )
            ->where('user_id', $user->record_id)
            ->get()
            ->groupBy('pay_week')
            ->map(function($entry) {
                return (object)[
                    'count' => $entry->count(),
                    'duration' => $entry->sum('total_duration'),
                    //'year' => $entry->sum('start_timestamp')->year,
                    'entries' => $entry
                ];
            });

        return view('user.timeclock.reports.all', [
            'entries' => $entries
        ]);
```

Comment: I think, there's no other way on the query directly but you could do that on the collection.

Comment: How would I do that @shaedrich

Comment: I've added it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

Given, that you set the cast in your model

```
class TimeClock extends Model
{
    protected $cast = [
        'start_timestamp' => 'datetime'
    ];
}
```

you can do the following:

```
$entries = TimeClock::select(
   'pay_week', 
   'start_timestamp', 
   'total_duration'
)
->where('user_id', $user->record_id)
//->groupBy('pay_week')
->get()
->groupBy([ 'pay_week', function($entry) {
    return $entry->start_timestamp->year
})
/*->map(function($entry) {
    return (object)[
        'count' => $entry->count(),
        'duration' => $entry->sum('total_duration'),
        'year' => $entry->start_timestamp->year,
        'entries' => $entry
    ];
})*/;
```

You loop over it like this:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Pay week</th>
            <th>Date range</th>
            <th>Year</th>
            <th>Total hours</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($entries as $pay_week => $groups)
            @foreach($groups as $year => $group)
                <!--pay_week: {{ $pay_week }}<br />
                count: {{ $group->count() }}<br />
                duration: {{ $group->sum('total_duration') }}<br />
                year: {{ $year }}<br />-->
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $pay_week }}</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>{{ $year }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $group->sum('total_duration') }}</td>
                </tr>
                @foreach($group as $entry)
                @endforeach
            @endforeach
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I need to have the entries object with the count, duration, and year in a single collection so I can run my foreach loop on the blade.

Comment: Also the query is to group count, duration, and year for each group of pay_week. so I can foreach loop a table to render the data set.

Comment: Also get Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'traqzawe_traqzasaas_staging.time_clock.start_timestamp' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by (SQL: select `pay_week`, `start_timestamp`, `total_duration` from `time_clock` where `user_id` = 1 and `time_clock`.`deleted_at` is null group by `pay_week`)

Comment: About your first comment: Oh, yeah, I forgot about that. Updated my answer.

Comment: About your third comment: I guess, with the current code, you can omit the `groupBy` on query level. Updated my answer.

Comment: So a user has 1 to many records per pay week; Im trying to count the total records a user has in a given pay week, sum the total duration for the entire payweek, and identify the year the payweek is. Then list each individual pay week with summations of that week.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, that's what you can do inside the outer foreach due to the `groupBy` of the collection

Comment: If you look at this screen shot https://ibb.co/PgHHGGt this is what I am trying to do overall. Im getting duplicates for the week, so its not grouping correctly. Also I cant get the year; Ill update my post to show what I have at this current moment.

Comment: ErrorException

Attempt to read property "year" on string

Comment: You have to cast it to `Carbon` in the model before as seen in the first code block of my answer